# Extra new line in Botframework V4 prompt

Tags: botframework

I write an Bot with Microsoft Botframework. In the newest version I got a problem with an extra new line on text prompts.

I want to display text like this:

```
Wenn Sie Ihre Eingabe so präzise wie möglich formulieren, kann ich Sie am besten verstehen und eine passende Antwort finden.

Diese Eingabe ist nicht sehr präzise:
"Kompetenzen Sollzinsänderung"

Schreiben Sie stattdessen doch lieber:
"Welche Kompetenzen benötige ich für die Änderung eines individuell vereinbarten Sollzinses?"
```

I load this text from an resource file and send it via context.PromptAsync to the client. The client renderd it like this:

```
Wenn Sie Ihre Eingabe so präzise wie möglich formulieren, kann ich Sie am besten verstehen und eine passende Antwort finden.

Diese Eingabe ist nicht sehr präzise:
  
"Kompetenzen Sollzinsänderung"

Schreiben Sie stattdessen doch lieber:

"Welche Kompetenzen benötige ich für die Änderung eines individuell vereinbarten Sollzinses?"
```

I know that a markdown interpreter is used to render the text. Does someone know how to format the resource string, to get the first output?

Edit:
My resource Text is as shown in the first code section.

The Code to get the resource text is as follows:
BaseDialog.cs

```
public class BaseDialog : ComponentDialog{
    private readonly IStringLocalizer<BaseDialog> _stringLocalizer;
    public BaseDialog(string dialogId, IStringLocalizer<BAseDialog> stringLocalizer) : base(dialogId)
    {
        _stringLocalizer = stringLocalizer ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(stringLocalizer));

        AddDialog(new TextPrompt(PROMPTDIALOGID));
    }

    protected override async Task<DialogTurnResult> OnBeginDialogAsync(DialogContext innerDc, object options, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        var activity = GetActivity().AsMessageActivity();

        return await innerDc.PromptAsync(PROMPTDIALOGID, new PromptOptions
        {
            Prompt = (Activity)activity
        }, cancellationToken);
    }

    public virtual IActivity GetActivity()
    {
        return MessageFactory.Text(Localizer["Default_Response"]);
    }
}
```

HelpDialog.cs

```
public class HelpDialog : BaseDialog
{
    public HelpHandlingDialog(IStringLocalizer<BaseDialog> localizer)
        : base(nameof(HelpDialog), localizer)
    {
    }

    public override IActivity GetActivity()
    {
       return MessageFactory.Text(Localizer["Help_Response"]);
    }
}
```

We are using the Directline and test with BotFramework Emulator and for the users we are using the ReactWebchat. The described behaviour is present in both clients.

Comment: Can you please share your code?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please have a look at the handy guide to see the steps you can take to get a better answer faster: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: In addition to sharing your code, please let us know what channel you're using. (Since there are multiple other people in this thread, you will need to @ mention me if you want me to see your reply.)

Comment: @KyleDelaney I add the requested information to the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So one of my co-workers did the task and got a solution to the problem.

These is the code to eliminate the extra new lines:

BaseDialog.resx
Wenn Sie Ihre Eingabe so präzise wie möglich formulieren, kann ich Sie am besten verstehen und eine passende Antwort finden.

```
Diese Eingabe ist nicht sehr präzise: \\n "Kompetenzen Sollzinsänderung"

Schreiben Sie stattdessen doch lieber:\\n “Welche Kompetenzen benötige ich für die Änderung eines individuell vereinbarten Sollzinses?”
```

HelpDialog.cs

```
public class HelpgDialog : BaseDialog
{
    public HelpDialog(IStringLocalizer<BaseDialog> localizer)
        : base(nameof(HelpDialog), localizer)
    {
    }

    public override IActivity GetActivity()
    {
        return MessageFactory.Text(Localizer["Help_Response"].Value.Replace("\\n","\n"));
    }
}
```